# ANTLR grammar how to capture all characters to end of line

Tags: c#, antlr

I'm trying to capture a command that looks like 
_SC play Piano 1
to a tree with 3 nodes "_SC" "play" and "Piano 1"

the grammar I've got so far is

```
grammar PBScript;
options {
output = AST;
language = CSharp2;
}

line    :       COMMAND WS ACTION;
COMMAND :   '_SC';
ACTION  :   'play';
WS  :   (' '|'\t')+ ;
```

When I create another rule to capture the "Piano 1" part like so:

```
grammar PBScript;
options {
output = AST;
language = CSharp2;
}

line    :       COMMAND WS ACTION WS PARAMETER;
COMMAND :   '_SC';
ACTION  :   'play';
WS  :   (' '|'\t')+;
PARAMETER
    :       (~('\n'|'\r'))+ ;
```

I get a MismatchedTokenException(6!=5).  I get that the grammar is wrong and I know partially why it's wrong. It's ambiguous because WS overlaps PARAMETER.  I just don't know how to fix it.

There are other actions besides _SC and PARAMETER should be optional there will even be a different line type eventually that looks like `Name: blah blah blah`where I'll at least need "Name" and "blah blah blah" in the tree just in case that matters, but right now I'm just trying to figure out what to use for PARAMETER.

~Tom

EDIT: The string "Piano 1" should be any string of non newline characters so from the first non whitespace after play to the end of the line.

Comment: Can't you change your grammar so that the command is _SC play "Piano 1", instead of _SC play Piano 1? The quotes would remove the ambiguity.

Comment: The doublequote characters are valid as part of the string.  If I was expecting only other programmers to use this I could force them to escape the doublequote, but I'm handing this to people who aren't particularly computer friendly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use a `PARAMETER` rule like that in your lexer. ANTLR's lexer matches tokens greedily: so `PARAMETER` would gobble up the entire line: no `COMMAND` or `ACTION` tokens will ever be created.

To be able to match something to the end of the line, you'd need a parser rule for it. But then the parser *must* have a notion of what a new line is (i.e. the lexer will need to produce new-line tokens).

```
grammar T;

options {
  output=AST;
}

tokens {
  LINE;
  PARAMS;
}

line
 : COMMAND ACTION rest_of_line NL 
   -> ^(LINE COMMAND ACTION ^(PARAMS rest_of_line))
 ;

rest_of_line
 : ~NL* // match any token other than a line break zero or more times
 ;

COMMAND : '_SC';
ACTION  : 'play';
WORD    : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+;
NUMBER  : '0'..'9';
WS      : (' '|'\t')+ {skip();};
NL      : '\r'? '\n' | '\r';
```

If you now parse your input `"_SC play Piano 1"` you'd end up with the following AST:

[image]

Comment: Hi Bart, I would like to ask you about PARAMETER rule in the user1237541's grammar. You said that ANTLR's lexer matches tokens greedily: so PARAMETER would gobble up the entire line: no COMMAND or ACTION tokens will ever be created. But I thought that if COMMAND token is defined Before PARAMETER token, parser will match COMMAND token. Is this a case? Tnx.

Comment: @VladimirRadojicic, only if both rules match the same amount of characters, the one defined first will "win". Since `PARAMETER` matches the most characters, *it* "wins".

Comment: I think that's what I'm looking for, but when I parse it I get something slightly different. [link](http://bayimg.com/NAMBHAAdp)

Comment: @majinnaibu, you're probably using the interpreter from ANTLRWorks. Don't. It's notoriously buggy. Try the debugger instead (the AST-image I posted is from the debugger).

Answer (score 1):

This grammar will parse your _SC play Piano 1 statement:

```
grammar PBScript;
options {
language = CSharp2;
output=AST;
}
tokens
{
COMMAND;
ACTION;
PARAM;
}

program :   lines;

lines   :   line*;

line:   'command:' command  action parameter param_modifier 
    ;

command
    :   IDENTIFIER
    ->  ^(COMMAND IDENTIFIER)
    ;

action  :   IDENTIFIER
    ->      ^(ACTION IDENTIFIER)
    ;

parameter   :   IDENTIFIER
    ->  ^(PARAM IDENTIFIER)
    ;

param_modifier  :   INTEGER
    ;

IDENTIFIER  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*
    ;

INTEGER :   '0'..'9'+ 
    ;


COMMENT
    :   '//' ~('\n'|'\r')* '\r'? '\n' {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    |   '/*' ( options {greedy=false;} : . )* '*/' {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;

WS  :   ( ' '
        | '\t'
        | '\r'
        | '\n'
        ) {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;
```

Then for the input:

```
command: _SC play Piano 1

command: _SR doSomething someInstrument 2
```

You will get following parse tree:

[image]

Then, when you make your AST grammar you should chek the names of the commands for you commands, for example: `if Name Of command == _SC do something` etc...